# Is it clear to non-tech users that “share page” on this mockup means share the page user was on when menu was clicked

Tags: menu, sharing, intuitive

Looking for insight about a non-tech user's experience and whether or not they'll understand that "share page" refers to the page from which the menu was called.

[image: Mobile website mockup of what appears when menu is pressed from any page]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very clear. My 66 year old mom, day care center attendant knows what to do - and she's a non-tech user by all means.

I congratulate you for a good design!

You could add the iOS7 share icon to make it even more obvious!

[image]